# Which Subversion do I install for Windows?

Tags: windows, svn

I was reading this article on Coding Horror:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/setting-up-subversion-on-windows.html

I went to the downloads and am confused.  I would have just downloaded the first entry but I am afraid it would break my server or something if I don't have apache.  We use IIS only and I wouldn't want to break it somehow.  I don't even need a web or webdav front end.

Which one should I install on this page, please:

http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=91

thank you for any help.

edit:  thanks for information, but I am hoping to stay free with the "regular" subversion.  I plan on using TortoiseSVN for the client.

**Edit:** Please use http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows if you need recent Windows binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that list, you want the Setup-Subversion-1.5.6.msi.  Don't worry about the apache bindings, if you don't use them, they won't interfere.  After you install the subversion executables, install TortoiseSVN on top, tortoise doesn't include the svn executables.

edit:  Strike that, you'll want to get subversion 1.6.x.  Check out the CollabNet distributions (http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) and get the 1.6.9 build.  That's what the latest Tortoise is built against.

Comment: I ended up with 1.6.6 tigris version because the collab .net version made me think I had to pay money.

Comment: While it's true that "tortoise doesn't include the svn executables" I'd like to add that it doesn't depends on them. It's nice to have both tortoise and the command line stuff though.

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/), it's very easy to set up and the server software is free. Then for your client machine(s) I'd say you want to install [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)

Comment: This is exactly the setup I use; VisualSVN server and TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 2):

Your download link is a bit dated, the Subversion project has recently moved homepages.  Try the download links at [subversion.apache.org](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html).  In particular, click on "CollabNet" under the "Windows" heading and try the topmost download option.  If you need more information about setting up a server, take a look at the e-book ["Version Control with Subversion"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html); this is the "official" Subversion book and covers every aspect of using Subversion, from setting up and administering a server to using it as a normal developer.

As for client software, I agree with several other posters here that [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) is a great graphical utility for Windows.

Comment: Note that the CollabNet version is the basic server, compiled for Windows. This will get a running svn server up, but only using the svn protocol which is NOT encrypted. So, this may not be suitable for production.
The packages with Apache will run subversion through a web server so you can use https. This may be what you have to do if you need security. Apache will have to run on a different port than IIS, of course.

Comment: AngerClown forgot to mention that the svn protocol can be encrypted, at least with recent releases of Subversion.  I believe the protocol is referred to as `svn+ssh://` (that is, the normal `svnserve` daemon through a SSH tunnel).  No web server is needed.  More information is available in the SVN book listed above.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with most that [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) is the best svn client, but if you want integration with Visual Studio [AnhkSvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) is good. If you want to get really crazy I believe they work side by side.